# Simultaneous fit with shared parameters

Tags: r, curve-fitting

I have different datasets like this

```
   t    y        a1    a2     a3           a4       a5         a6
1  0.00 19.404   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
2  0.05 19.398   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
3  0.10 19.391   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
4  0.15 19.386   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
5  0.20 19.381   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
6  0.25 19.377   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
7  0.30 19.372   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
8  0.35 19.368   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
9  0.40 19.363   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
10 0.45 19.359   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
```

where a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6 are constant for each dataset but change for the different datasets.

What I would like to do is to fit simultaneously this function to all the datasets

```
f <- function(data,pars) {
  par1 <- pars[1]
  par2  <- pars[2]
  par3  <-  pars[3]
  t  <- data[,1]
  y  <- data[,2]
  a1 <- data[,3]
  a2 <- data[,4]
  a3 <- data[,5]
  a4 <- data[,6]
  a5 <- data[,7]
  a6 <- data[,8]  

  Tinf <- a2 - (par2*(1-a3)*a4)/(1+par2*a5*a4)
  kC <-par1*sqrt(a6)
  V <- par1 + par3
  tau <- 1/(V*(1+par2*a5*a4))

  y <- a1 -(a1-Tinf)*(1-exp(-t/tau))
  return(y)
}
```

The parameters `par1`, `par2`, `par3` need to be the same for all the datasets. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a dplyr approach that needs to combine (rbind) your datasets, after giving them a unique id (identifier). Then it groups by that id and performs your process/function to each dataset. I've created my own data in order to have two datasets to play with.

Also, I've slightly modified your function to specify parameters outside the function and consider unique a1,...,a6 values for each dataset. If you're not happy with that I can update my process with the minimum possible change to your function.

```
dt1 = 
read.table(text="
t    y        a1    a2     a3           a4       a5         a6
1  0.00 19.404   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
2  0.05 19.398   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
3  0.10 19.391   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
4  0.15 19.386   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
5  0.20 19.381   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
6  0.25 19.377   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
7  0.30 19.372   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
8  0.35 19.368   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
9  0.40 19.363   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3
10 0.45 19.359   20    0.6    19.404       22       0.06       3", header=T)

dt2 = 
  read.table(text="
t    y        a1    a2     a3           a4       a5         a6
1  0.00 21.409   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07      5
2  0.05 21.398   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
3  0.10 21.397   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
4  0.15 21.386   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
5  0.20 21.381   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
6  0.25 21.377   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
7  0.30 21.371   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
8  0.35 21.368   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
9  0.40 21.363   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5
10 0.45 21.351   20    0.8    19.409       20       0.07       5", header=T)


# create an id for each dataset
dt1$id = 1
dt2$id = 2

# bind datasets
dt = rbind(dt1,dt2)

# input parameters
par1 = 2
par2 = 3
par3 = 4


library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  do({ Tinf <- unique(.$a2) - (par2*(1-unique(.$a3))*unique(.$a4))/(1+par2*unique(.$a5)*unique(.$a4))
       kC <-par1*sqrt(unique(.$a6))
       V <- par1 + par3
       tau <- 1/(V*(1+par2*unique(.$a5)*unique(.$a4)))
       y <- unique(.$a1) -(unique(.$a1)-Tinf)*(1-exp(-.$t/tau))

       data.frame(y) })


#    id        y
# 1   1  20.0000
# 2   1 194.5705
# 3   1 233.9927
# 4   1 242.8951
# 5   1 244.9055
# 6   1 245.3595
# 7   1 245.4620
# 8   1 245.4852
# 9   1 245.4904
# 10  1 245.4916
# 11  2  20.0000
# 12  2 172.6108
# 13  2 204.6799
# 14  2 211.4187
# 15  2 212.8348
# 16  2 213.1324
# 17  2 213.1949
# 18  2 213.2080
# 19  2 213.2108
# 20  2 213.2114
```

If you want your function results joined back to your initial (combined) dataset, just use this in the end : `data.frame(dt,y_res=y)`